# Is it possible to make questions to these sentences?

Tags: questions

1) This is my second stay here.

2) This is the second time I have been here.

3) This is our second lesson.

**Are these possible and idiomatic/or passable?**

1) Which number stay of yours is it?

2) What time is this you have been here?

3) What number lesson is this?

Comment: No, they aren't. If you can ask a more specific question about what you're finding difficult about this, I'm sure someone will be willing and able to help./

Comment: @SamBC I find it difficult as well. It is even possible to have questions formed so that the given answers answer them precisely?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko: Not without them being excessively convoluted and - for that reason if no other - entirely unnatural.

Comment: @SamBC I would be so grateful if you had a look at this: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/199854/given-the-answer-its-my-first-time-here-what-questions-could-i-ask-to-receiv

Answer (score 2):

If you want to directly convert the statements into questions (in other words, you are not trying to pose questions which would cause the statements to be answers)

> Is this your second stay here?
>
> Is this the second time you have stayed here?
>
> Is this the second lesson?

In other words, it is the very basic English manner of creating a question by reversing the order of the subject and verb. These all create yes/no answers.

But if you are trying to create questions which might cause someone to answer with the statements you cited, you do the following:

The idiom you would want is 'how many' in each case. It is an extremely common expression for asking about amounts. You would use 'how many' for countable items, and 'how much' for uncountable ones.

> How many times have you stayed here?
>
> How many times have you been here?
>
> How many lessons have there been?

Comment: Great answer, upvoted. Could you have a look at a similar question? https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/199854

Answer (score 0):

You could say:

Have you stayed here before?

How many times have you visited?

I’ll let you practise on the third...